# How To Get All Site Users in Sharepoint using Soap Services

Tags: sharepoint-online, soap

I am Using SOAP Service to Get SharePoint Data. Now I want To Get All Site Users details.

How Can I get It?

Comment: @AsadRefai i was getting through rest API but I want it  using SOAP